# Adding activity manually

Tags: java, android, android-activity, adt

Hi I am developing an application in android using Java.I have added a new java class in my project which extends ListActivity.But  I did it manually,so the .xml file was not  produced.Is there a way I can create a new .xml file and somehow connect it with the newly created class?

Comment: You should consider reading some tutorials on Android programming, cause this is really a basic question.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate? or is it a bad question and you downvote it?

Comment: well I am reading the adt documentation.I didn't see that,no reason you should be judgemental or to put it better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[assuming you are using eclipse]

**to create the layout file (XML):**

- from the navigator, go to  -> res -  -> right Click on layout - > new ->Android xml file
- you can edit this xml acc to your needs using the xml editor integrated in eclipse.

**to use this xml in your activity:**

- use the `setContentView()` method to refer the xml file created
- for eg: if the name of your new xml is `new.xml` and you created this in the way i mentioned above you say `setContentView(R.layout.new);`

Comment: well  i did that but still eclipse won't find the newly added xml...should i add anywhere else?

Comment: well i figured it out..it doesn't seem that clear to me so i will post it because i still think my question was legit.After you have added it in layout you should add a new .xml with the same name in menu folder...hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The layout xml is just a standard xml file, in the layout directory create a new layout xml file.  In the new Activity class you created you then refer to it by using the setContentView method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Go to Your **Project->res(folder)->layout->right click to create new xml file** and link it to your class.